# Creating two different objects through one Perl module

Tags: perl, oop, object, module, subroutine

I'm writing Perl modules that allow users to create `file` and `directory` objects to manipulate the file system.

**Example:**

```
use File;
use Dir;

my $file = File->new("path");
my $dir  = Dir ->new("path");
```

This works out nicely, but what I would really like to be able to create both `file` and `directory` objects without having to `use` two separate modules.

---

To do this I came up with the following solution...

**IO.pm:**

```
use File;
use Dir;

use Exporter qw(import);
our @EXPORT_OK = qw(file dir);

sub file {
    my $path = shift;
    return File->new($path);
}

sub dir {
    my $path = shift;
    return Dir->new($path);
}

1;
```

**test.pl:**

```
use IO qw(file dir);

my $file = file("path");
my $dir  = dir ("path");
```

---

Now here's the problem, by doing this I eliminate the explicit call to `new` when the user creates a `file` or `directory` object.  I'm sort of using the `file` and `dir` subroutines as constructors.

To me this code looks very clean, and is extremely simple to use, but I haven't seen many other people writing Perl code like this so I figured I should at least pose the question:

***Is it okay to simply return an object from a subroutine like this, or does this scream bad practice?***

Comment: I have a feeling you're going to say that this is just an example you made up and not what you're actually working on, but...FYI, [Path::Tiny](https://metacpan.org/pod/Path::Tiny) already gives a pretty complete OO API for interacting with the filesystem.

Comment: (And Path::Tiny's [`path`](https://metacpan.org/pod/Path::Tiny#path) function is just syntactic sugar for `Path::Tiny->new`, so no, the approach you've described is not bad practice.)

Comment: Awesome! Thanks @ThisSuitIsBlackNot!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's perfectly fine.

For example, Path::Class's `file` and `dir` functions return Path::Class::File and Path::Class::Dir objects respectively.

If that was the only constructor the class provided, it would prevent (clean) subclassing, but that's not the case here.

---

There is, however, the question of whether replacing

```
open(my $fh, "path");
opendir(my $dh, "path);
```

with

```
my $fh = file("path");
my $dh = dir("path);
```

is advantageous or not (assuming the functions return IO::File and IO::Dir objects).

Comment: Ikegami, you are literally the most helpful person on the internet.  You have answered like 90% of all of my Perl questions haha.